# How to add container.clusters.update permission to service account?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to delete a node pool using a service account with ‘K8s Engine admin’ role which supposed to have full cluster permissions including API objects. I am using the sa.json in my chaostoolkit manifest (it’s an open source chaos tool). However, i get below error:

> failed: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when
> requesting
> https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/chaos/zones/us-east1-b/clusters/chaos/nodePools/pool-1?alt=json
> returned "Required "container.clusters.update" permission(s) for
> "projects/chaos/zones/us-east1-b/clusters/chaos"

I would assume K8s engine admin role should have every permission needed on the clusters.
Any help on how to add this specific permission to this SA or a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the permissions were sufficient. After I added 'k8s context' parameter in the chaostoolkit manifest it worked. This is how it should look:

> secrets:
> k8s:
> KUBERNETES_CONTEXT: gke_projectname_us-east1_chaos
> gcp:
> service_account_file: ./sa-k8s.json